# Render ninja form inside markup

Tags: php, templates, plugin-ninja-forms

I want to render a ninja form via markup (in a php file):

```php
<div>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <ninja-form>           <---- ?
</div>
```

What do i put in there to render a particular ninja form?

Comment: This is off topic as its a 3rd party plugin.  Also, a little effort on your part and you can easily google this.  Look toward the bottom of this page, https://ninjaforms.com/docs/form-building/, you probably want Method 2: Form Shortcodes, you can echo the shortcode in PHP

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I found a solution (without shortcodes) by digging into the code, posted below.

Comment: Tags have nothing to do with a question being ontopic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php Ninja_Forms()->display(123) ?>
```